using package parameter overrides with choco uninstall
I need to uninstall a package that is not finding the correct software registry key. I want to override the package parameter for 'softwareName'. Here is the command I'm using:
choco uninstall -d newforma --override --params '/softwareName:Newforma*'

Here is the output of the debug:
Calling built-in PowerShell host with ['[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = '';[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ''; & import-module -name 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1'; & 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyScriptRunner.ps1' -packageScript 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\newforma\tools\chocolateyuninstall.ps1' -installArguments '' -packageParameters '/softwareName:Newforma*' -overrideArgs']
Host version is 5.1.19041.1, PowerShell Version is '5.1.19041.5129' and CLR Version is '4.0.30319.42000'.
---------------------------Script Execution---------------------------
Running 'ChocolateyScriptRunner' for newforma v12.2.3.12933 with packageScript 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\newforma\tools\chocolateyuninstall.ps1', packageFolder:'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\newforma', installArguments: '', packageParameters: '/softwareName:Newforma*',
Running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\newforma\tools\chocolateyuninstall.ps1'
Running Get-UninstallRegistryKey -softwareName 'newforma12.1*'
Registry uninstall keys on system: 67
Error handling check: 'Get-ItemProperty' fails if a registry key is encoded incorrectly.
WARNING: No registry key found based on  'newforma12.1*'
Found 0 uninstall registry key(s) with SoftwareName:'newforma12.1*'
WARNING: newforma has already been uninstalled by other means.
Thanks for you help in advance.

Just to check, when you say "the package parameter for softwareName" are you referring to a package parameter, or the value passed to the softwareName parameter of (e.g.) Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage? If the latter, -params won't work to override it, I believe.

The --Override argument is only for use with the installargs parameter.
It can't be used to override the softwareName being passed in to, e.g., Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage (or further down, Get-UninstallRegistryKey).
You'll need to modify your uninstall script to say newforma* instead of newforma12.1*.
